# JSON schema "switch" not working

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to use the `switch` attribute of JSON schema v5 using the https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv library.

I have the following schema but it's not working.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "id": "http://localhost/drinks.json",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "switch": [
            {
              "if": {
                "properties": {
                  "type": {
                    "enum": ["coffee", "tea"]
                  }
                }
              },
              "then": {
                "$ref": "http://localhost/caffeinated.json"
              }
            },
            {
              "then": {
                "$ref": "http://localhost/decaf.json"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To be clear, the `$ref`s work just fine without the switch statement. For example, this gets validated correctly:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "id": "http://localhost/drinks.json",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "http://localhost/caffeinated.json"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "http://localhost/decaf.json"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the first schema doesn't work, and by "doesn't work" I mean it doesn't even trigger valid/invalid. Did I do something wrong?